# meaning of regular (In proof of hartshorne book lemma(II.6.1))

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be an integral scheme with generic point $x$.
Then $K=\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$ is a field and we call $K$ the function field of $X$
And I know that for any affine open subset ${\rm Spec}A$ of $X$, the quotient field of $A$ is isomorphic to $K$.

In proof of hartshorne book lemma(II.6.1))
for a nonzero element $f \in K$, let $U$ be an affine open subset of $X$ which $f$ is regular on $U$.

But I don't know the meaning of regular....
In case, what is that $f$ is regular?

Comment: That just means that $f$ is a section of $\mathcal O$ over $U$.